# jQuery data-action="save" button not posting for specific browsers

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that captures a signature and posts it to an mvc4 controller action. It works perfectly on IE, but not chrome, or some mobile devices. Any ideas why it doesn't post, or submit the form on some devices?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<form action="/Capture/Save" id="formSig" method="post">
    ...
    <button id="btnSave" class="button save" data-action="save" 
       onclick="return SaveButton_Click();">Save</button>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveButton_Click() {
        $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `type="submit"` might help.

Comment: @tymeJV  It's perfectly possible to use `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit">` to submit an HTML form.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what "doesn't work" about your code.

Comment: Doesn't submit the form. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By disabling the button, you are effectively canceling the submit event from happening (only tested it in chrome myself, 1 negative result is enough for me). You should instead be using the submit event to disable the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/7D7zj/

```
<form action="javascript:alert('Hello World!')" onsubmit="return FormSig_Submit()" id="formSig" method="post">
    ...
    <button id="btnSave" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    function FormSig_Submit() {
        $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

It would also be better (in my opinion) to not use inline events and `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

```
<form action="javascript:alert('Hello World!')" id="formSig" method="post">
    ...
    <button id="btnSave" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formSig").submit(function(){
            //$("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#btnSave").prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I substituted an alert for your form action to make it work in fiddle, etc.